# Explorer window pops up when using my keyboards volume wheel

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, windows-explorer

I have the weirdest problem right now, I don't know for sure when or how it started.

Thing is: I have a keyboard with a volume wheel that I can twist to turn up/down my windows volume, but whenever I use it, a windows explorer window pops up.

Also: when I haven't typed anything in a short while and I press any random button, same thing happens.

I scanned my computer for viruses and it's completely clean.

Does anyone have any idea at all what this could be?

Comment: The crystal ball is murky -- you'll need you to fill us in a little more. ;)   What kind of keyboard?  How is it attached?  Have you tried another keyboard?  Have you tired the KB on another computer? Have you tried checking/installing any manufacturer's software for controlling the keyboard?  Does it do it in Safe Mode?  Have you tried a System Restore to a point before you suspect it started doing this?

Comment: It is a Silvercrest wireless keyboard, I have not been able to try it on another computer, it doesn't do this in safemode and I did a system restore but since I only reformatted my PC two weeks ago, the earliest restore point is a day after it started happening. I also installed manufacturer drivers, tried to look in the settings but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: turned out the button to open explorer on my keyboard was a little stuck, which strangely resulted in it always opening when I use my volume wheel and at random times when I hadn't typed in a short while and typed again.

Solution was of course to unstuck it

stupid me